# Remover o Core Data de um projeto Xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, core-data

Iniciei um desenvolvimento de um aplicativo utilizando o `Core Data` no decorrer do desenvolvimento do projeto fui observando que o `Core Data` não é o melhor para o aplicativo.

Dentro deste cenário, gostaria de saber como faço para **remover o Core Data completamente** do meu aplicativo e dar continuidade ao desenvolvimento do mesmo sem ele.

Answer (score 1):

Como você não especificou se é Swift ou Objective-C, vou chutar que é Objective-C. Mas o processo em Swift é semelhante.

1. Selecione o projeto no `Project Navigator` -> `Build Phases` e em `Link Binary With Libraries` remova o `CoreData.framework`
2. (Pule esta etapa se for Swift) Procure pelo arquivo .pch do seu projeto. Normalmente o padrão é: **[Nome do seu projeto]-Prefix.pch**. Remova a linha do `#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>`
3. Delete qualquer arquivo ***.Model**
4. No `AppDelegate.h` delete as seguintes properties e métodos (No Swift são as `lazy var` de mesmo nome):

   - `@property (readonly, strong, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;
     @property (readonly, strong, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectModel *managedObjectModel;
     @property (readonly, strong, nonatomic) NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *persistentStoreCoordinator;`
   - `- (void)saveContext;`
     `- (NSURL *)applicationDocumentsDirectory;`
5. (Pule esta etapa se for Swift) No `AppDelegate.m` remova os `@synthesize` das properties que você acabou de remover:

   - `@synthesize managedObjectContext = _managedObjectContext;
     @synthesize managedObjectModel = _managedObjectModel;
     @synthesize persistentStoreCoordinator = _persistentStoreCoordinator;`
6. Ainda no `AppDelegate.m` delete os seguintes métodos:

   - `saveContext
     managedObjectContext
     managedObjectModel
     persistentStoreCoordinator
     applicationDocumentsDirectory`
7. E por último, ainda no `AppDelegate.m`, dentro do método `applicationWillTerminate` remova a chamada do método `[self saveContext]`

Pronto, você se livrou do CoreData!